# Ошибка в Mutations в vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Я пытаюсь создать такую мутацию:

```
INCREMENT: (state, index) => {
   Object.values(state.menu.food)[index].count++
},
```

в консоль выводится ошибка:

**vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'count')"**

Comment: Ну так Вы пытаетесь вызвать свойство элемента, а этого элемента не существует в массиве `state.menu.food`. Отсюда и ошибка. Или применяйте optional chaining, или пишите условие.

Comment: Он есть там, в food хранятся объекты и в каждом объекте count

Comment: Точно есть? Пропишите выше `console.log(Object.values(state.menu.food))` и посмотрите на результат